# Why should I buy a barrel of blood?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I just noticed a dwarven caravan brought about a dozen barrels of blood from various sources, and a few barrels of ichor too.

What's the use of this? If there's any, how can I "collect" the blood from my victims?

Comment: I have to say, Dwarf Fortress is quite possible the greatest game I have never played, and it will stay that way until these questions stop being awesome.

Comment: This title is well up there with "How can I butcher a leopard" for strangest question title.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of now, there isn't any in-game use for these other than selling them or general Armok-pleasing.

I also don't think that there's any way to collect them. I thought that this was what extracting at the butcher's shop did, but [according to the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Extract#Butcher.27s_shop), that's just for venom and liquid fire.

Hopefully there will be some use in the future though like transfusions, occupying night creatures for a while, or coating your fortress for decorations, but alas, this does not exist yet.

Comment: Can you dump or cook the blood?  My food store is currently so full of barrels I've lost track of the blood barrels, but I bought a bunch when my lumber limits were low (and I didn't want to piss off the elves yet) in hopes I could dump or cook the contents.